# Дистанция сканирования QR кода

Tags: qr

Есть проблема со сканированием QR кода сканером АТОЛ sb 2108 plus, QR код сканируется только с большой дистанции от 30 см. Возможно ли как то настроить и в чем может быть проблема? (Не до конца понятно проблема ли вообще, правда, но нужно разобарться.)

P.S. После сканирования с данными все в порядке, вопрос только в удобстве использования. Есть подозрение что дело в драйвере, но так как не специалист только подозрение. Обычные штрихкоды сканер видит как надо от 30 мм.

Answer (score 0):

Полагаю, что расстояние в лазерном считывателе QR-кода не настраивается и для разных QR-кодов расстояние будет разным в виду его размера (количества информации).

Мы можем заметить, что расстояние не критично для устройств, считывание QR-кода которых основано на компьютерном зрении - разработчики софта таких устройств имеют больше контроля над изображением, имеют возможность произвести его предварительную обработку (увеличить, повернуть). Лазерные считыватели ограничены в своих вычислительных способностях. Поэтому вполне ожидаемо, что они имеют какие-то ограничения, которые, скорее всего, нерешаемы в виду конструктивных особенностей устройства.

Я рекомендую вам обратиться к продавцу устройства с вопросом или претензией по поводу ошибок считывания. Возможно, они предложат готовое решение или другое устройство, в котором этой проблемы нет.